# Issues with tkinter IntVar

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I was using python tkinter. What the code is supposed to do is printing 'insert km when the radio button 'miles to km' was ticked. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()


def radio_button_activate():
    print(radio_state.get())


radio_state = IntVar()
radio_1 = Radiobutton(text="km to miles", value=1,
                      variable=radio_state, command=radio_button_activate)
radio_2 = Radiobutton(text="miles to km", value=2,
                      variable=radio_state, command=radio_button_activate)
radio_1.grid(row=3, column=3)
radio_2.grid(row=3, column=4)


if radio_state.get() == 1:
    print('insert km')

window.mainloop()
```

[image: here is a screenshot of my program]

For some reason, the 'insert km' won't print.

```
type(radio_state.get())
```

is int.

Why is this not working? Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect to see a string from a `IntVar`?  BTW, you need to move the `if` block inside `radio_button_activate()`.

Comment: You're calling `radio_state.get()` about a millisecond after creating the radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

When the following code is executed, there is no radiobutton selected, so the if condition will be evaluated as `False` and nothing will be printed.

```py
if radio_state.get() == 1:
    print('insert km')
```

You need to move the above if block into `radio_button_activate()`:

```py
def radio_button_activate():
    print(radio_state.get())
    if radio_state.get() == 1:
        print('insert km')
    else:
        print('insert miles')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But why would there be no radiobutton selected? I'm a beginner, so explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The initial value of `radio_state` is zero if it is not set explicitly when it is created, so no radiobutton will be selected.  I would suggest you to go through some tutorials on [`event-driven programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) which tkinter application is based on.